# How to supplement __repr__() of parent class in subclass to output additional subclass features

Tags: python, python-3.x

Lets say I have parent class A and child class B like this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"My name is: {self.name}"

class B(A):
    def __init__(self,name,surname):
        super(B,self).__init__(name)
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"My name is: {self.name} {self.surname}"
    
a = A("Jhon")
b = B("Bon","Boby")


print(a)
print(b)
```

Is there any way to modify the `B.__repr__()` without repeating code from parent class and use `A.__repr__()` to just append the *surname* to its value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution that seems to work is to call `super(B,self).__repr__()` within B's `__repr__()` like this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"My name is: {self.name}"

class B(A):
    def __init__(self,name,surname):
        super(B,self).__init__(name)
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
    
    def __repr__(self):
        s = super(B,self).__repr__()
        s += f" {self.surname}"
        return s
    
a = A("Jhon")
b = B("Bon","Boby")


print(a)
print(b)
```